# MySql Pool - update query does not commit via Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm really new with Python and currently I'm trying to understand how it works and I'm building small codes for practising.
I have a table contains the details of the users: called luzer.
I want to update the password field (called: JELSZO in the table) is a varbinary (1000).
The MysqlDB connection works via a pool.
So, I use this def to execute Sql queries and commit updates etc...

```
    def execute(self, sql, args=None, commit=False):
    """ Execute a sql """
    # get connection form connection pool.
    conn = self.pool.get_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    if args:
        cursor.execute(sql, args)
    else:
        cursor.execute(sql)
    if commit is True:
        conn.commit()
        self.close(conn, cursor)
        return None
    else:
        res = cursor.fetchall()
        self.close(conn, cursor)
        return res
```

And this is how I try to update the password field (JELSZO)

```
sql_update_query = "Update luzer SET JELSZO = %s where AZON = %s" #the AZON is the userid in the table.
pas2 = testing(MySQLPool, sql_update_query, (jelszoid1, loginid, ), True) #if the commit = True then it should run the conn.commit() above.
```

It runs without any error but when I try to check if it commited the update succesfully then I see that nothing happend.
The password is a binary string (generated using Fernet Key).

I would really appreciate if you have any idea what could go wrong here?

Comment: Ok. I debugged from row to row and although , this function call contains the 'TRUE' for the commit (pas2 = testing(MySQLPool, sql_update_query, (jelszoid1, loginid, ), True)) but the running process does not go into the main If condition (if commit is True: conn.commit()) but leapt to the else condition.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this bloody issue. I used a different named def for it.

```
def update(request, bid, *args, **kwargs):
    mysql_pool = MySQLPool()
    query = sql_update_query
    result = mysql_pool.execute(query, (jelszoid1, loginid,), True)
    print('RESULT : \n', result)
    return result
```

while the original (def testing now I renamed to 'selection') function stayed as it was:

```
def selection(request, bid, *args, **kwargs):
    mysql_pool = MySQLPool()
    query = query1
    result = mysql_pool.execute(query, (loginid,), False)
    print('RESULT : \n', result)
    return result
```

As you can see the only difference is between the parameters of the function call.
I was stupid because I disregarded the basic sql rule that the select queries do not need commit.